# Remove element with CSS without ID

Tags: html, css, wordpress

i am working with WordPress theme, i have an Subheading menu that is displaying an title on my page. In the theme options when i change the name or just trying to let it empty the subheading doesn't update for unknown reason. I checked bug-list and I found many reports for this.How i can remove the element using css?If i inspect i get this:
[Photo] [1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3IKk.png

So how i should remove that using only CSS? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The element cannot be deleted in the CSS. It can be hidden

```
.container h6{
  display:none!important;
 }
```

Comment: Solved. Thank you.

Comment: If it is useful, please confirm my answer

Comment: it will work only when `C` will `c`. i don't  know how's OP says that it worked

Answer (score 1):

to be sure you only remove this one heading as the selector `.container h6` may possibly also affect other headings better use:

```
#wrap .titlebar .titlebar-inner .container h6 {
    display: none!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Chrome inspector, right click that element and choose 'Copy > Copy selector' then just use that selector to set it to `display: none;`

Answer (score 0):

you can remove it with js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$( document ).ready(function() {
var list = $("html").find("h6");
console.log(list);
$.each(list, function( index, value ) {
  if (value.innerText  == "Sub heading far far away"){
    list[index].remove();
  }
});
});

</script>
```

Comment: My friend is just using the CSS.

Comment: @FarhadBagherlo  agreed to you

Comment: DCR   OP clearly says:- `So how i should remove that using only CSS? Thanks.`

Answer (score 0):

```
.titlebar-inner .container h6 {
    display : none !important;
}
```